# Why does my Windows Explorer no longer refresh itself?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Normally when you do a file operation in Windows Explorer then Explorer refreshes itself. So I delete a file, and it's gone.

But since yesterday when I for example delete a file, the file entry doesn't disappear. It only disappears when closing and reopening the folder, or when pressing F5. What could that be?

Comment: And you are deleting the file using Windows Explorer as well? And did you restart your computer since you have that problem?

Comment: I had similiar problems after i installed "SuRun". It had to do with "fast user switching" and explorer.exe running in different user contexts. Did you install any software recently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/8afb8b65-900c-4f42-b1df-3c2394417b6e) in the Microsoft TechNet forums.  This may be related to a known issue with Windows 7.

Comment: To save you the trouble, I went and reviewed the whole (gigantic) thread. I'm having this issue myself. The conclusion of the folks in there as well as the MS person was that it's a bug in Windows 7 that they were able to reproduce. There's some button-mashing solutions that seemed to work for a few people like deleting the icon cache or resetting folder views. Worth a try, though none of that worked for me so far.

Comment: Another thread on the issue.. http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/w7files/thread/d2be04cb-7e8c-4e84-9890-7e29ee103e8d?prof=required

Comment: Resetting the folders worked for me (at least the error hasn't occurred since)
Thx for the link.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was caused by an unreachable network drive.

As soon as I deleted it from Network Places, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I've also struggled with this problem, and I've found a workaround from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/18601616-19a4-4783-8133-349e60be7c1b).

*This edit has been added by soandos: The post suggests that you install [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/)  from sourceforge.net. 
You can set the right pane auto-refresh like this:
Start > All Programs (or Programs) > Explorer Settings > Navigation Pane > Always navigate to the selected folder*
**Answer by Ciove**: The above is only partially true and, in my mind, doesn't solve the problem satisfactorily. See my comment below for details.

Classic Shell has also classic XP Start menu, if you want it.

Comment: **Comment to edit of soandos**: The _Always navigate to the selected folder_ -option works ONLY if you navigate by clicking the folder with mouse. If you navigate with arrow keys or by typing the first letter(s) of the folder name, the option DOESN'T WORK. This will result to a situation where in right pane pane you don't see the content of the folder you have selected.

Answer (score 1):

SYSTEM: Windows 7 SP1 32bit

SYMPTOM:
Files deleted in the "Documents" folder of the user (working with Admin rights) "Libraries" did not disappear immediately, but only after a subsequent refresh of the folder view.

SOLUTION:
Right-click on the "Documents" folder, select "Properties". Under "Optimize this library for:" (translated from Spanish, sorry if not entirely correct) change "Documents" to "General elements".

Comment: This doesn't address the problem asked

Comment: @Luke How do you figure? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read fully... comment redacted

Comment: This worked for me. File manipulation worked fine for me, it just randomly stopped refreshing itself after doing a file operation. Doing this made it refresh itself again. FWIW: I am on Windows 8.1. So I guess this problem never truly went away. I do have an SSD, which the mega thread above mentions. So it could be related to that.

Answer (score 0):

I found another article saying that the effect appears as soon as you open any Windows Explorer window. I tried this out and it really depends on the Windows Explorer on my machine.

Once a Windows Explorer has been opened, file changes are not being refreshed. To kill this effect, I have to close ALL explorer.exe processes and start only one through the Task Manager. Refreshing then works fine until you open another Windows Explorer window.

It seems like I have to use an Explorer alternative like Total Commander for file management. It really is unbelievable that Microsoft still hasn't brought out a patch; this bug seems to have been talked about around the web for over six months now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution which has resolved my problem:
 http://www.winvistaclub.com/t46.html

It is a `registry` file to execute (safe mode: check the content before in case this site is not more reliable) but I think such solution should be provided by Microsoft. All the microsoft links / solution in technet, social etc... previously mentionned in this topic were not working for me.

Hope this can help some others.

Answer (score 0):

Select your C drive in the Explorer and go into Organize/Folders and check the search options/View/Reset Folders option.

Answer (score -1):

There is a known problem for this in the Microsoft Knowledgebase for people who have disabled UAC, see [Desktop items disappear after renaming them on Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2018895).

The only fix on that article is to switch UAC back on, or keep pressing Refresh or <kbd>F5</kbd> when you make a change to a file.

Comment: This is absolutely not true. I have this issue despite always having UAC enabled.

Comment: @Peon that doesn't make this untrue, that just means that you're seeing a different angle to the problem than Microsoft are posting about. There could be people who are having this problem who have UAC disabled and might be helped out by this. I'm definitely seeing it in an environment that has UAC disabled, and unfortunately can't do much about that due to legacy app compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

Just restart `explorer.exe`

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
2. Click *Start Task Manager*
3. Click on *Processes* > find "explorer.exe"
4. End "explorer.exe"
5. Click *File* -> *New Task(Run)*, and type "explorer.exe" and press OK

Comment: -1 This is more cumbersome than a simple refresh, and doesn't resolve the problem.