# File timestamps inconsistently update on network drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, c++, timestamp, visual-studio-2005, vb6

This problem has been bugging me for a couple years now, and I have not been able to find a good solution.  I develop code in both C++ and VB6.  When I compile my C++ code in Visual Studio 2005, the file timestamps of the compiled files (exes, dlls, etc) are not updated when they are overwritten by the new versions unless I manually force a refresh of the folder containing them.  However, when I build in VB6, the timestamps are always instantly updated.  Does anyone know why this happens in one and not the other, and if there is a way to get time stamps to always update automatically?

Comment: If you get the timestamp *twice* in succession, is the second result correct? Sorry, I cannot remember where I read about someone having the same problem to give a reference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.  What do you mean by "get", precisely?  If I have the folder open with the files in it, and e.g. I build an .exe, the .exe's timestamp doesn't change.  Even if I copy paste it somewhere else, the timestamp in the new location will be correct, but the original will be wrong until I refresh the original folder.

Comment: Oops, I thought you meant that you were using a VB6/C++ program to retrieve the timestamps and only the former gave the correct result. I'll leave my earlier comment so no-one else makes the same misinterpretation.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  I added some more detail to make it less confusing.

Comment: Maybe something in [Why does my Windows Explorer no longer refresh itself?](http://superuser.com/questions/70532/why-does-my-windows-explorer-no-longer-refresh-itself) and its linked threads will help. There's a lot to read through, but if you've been waiting a couple of years... ;)